# Wildcard subdomain redirection

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have hosted a wildcard domain on one of my server what i am looking forward to do is to add following .htaccess rules:

```
http://www.domain.com/ -> index.php
http://domain.com/ -> index.php
http://*.domain.com/ -> category.php?id=[What ever subdomain is visited]
http://*.domain.com/Some_underscored_Link-123123 -> prodcutdetails.php?id=[What ever subdomain is visited]&id=123213
```

Moreover the URL on the browser should not be changed when the redirection occurs.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for that i would try to mark answers from now on-wards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a few `RewriteCond`'s:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
```

The name of your subdomain is then available in `RewriteRule`'s as `%1`

Comment: I happen to do it but for category and product details it doesn't work. :( Plus it changes the url

Comment: Without showing the code you actually tried... hard to tell where you're going wrong (you _do_ set the proper flags in your rulte BTW?).